# Handling python crash when handling recursion limit

Tags: python, recursion, exception, crash, crash-dumps

Imagine this code:

```py
def a():
    try:
        a()
    except RecursionError:
        a()
a()
```

It seems like the snippet would run `a` function recursively and infinitely.
But what really happens:

1. create recursion error
2. handle the exception, because you can handle every exception
3. do the same thing over again
   Result:
   python freaks out and crashes (this is impossible to handle by any mean known by me, because this doesn't raise error, it **crashes** python interpreter

For anyone to see what exception it raises:

```
Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00007f2e14fca180 (most recent call first):  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 5 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3 in a
  ...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

#### Update:

For python 3.10+ the code no longer crashes the interpreter, just hangs it (this is the expected behavior), but I can't find any information whatsoever about it in the [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html). The only change related to recursions that I've found is [bpo-41936](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/22552).

The interesting thing about running that code, is that the interpreter after running for a bit of time does not respond to keyboard interrupt (but when I hold `ctrl+c` for a bit longer the interpreter crashes with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`) - this is likely caused by the fact that the trace-back object gets enormously large and creating a formatted error just fails.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just increase the system recursion limit?

```py
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000000)
```

Comment: Did you tested your answer, because your number is to big, so python raises error that the number is not possible to convert into C int + it still crashes whenever I run my code, just need to wait about +1 second.

Comment: Sorry I was exaggerating for demonstrative purposes. But you can increase the limit quite high. I'll edit with the max i found.

Comment: By the way this solution won't prevent Python from eventually crashing but it might help extend how long it takes. Your code is slightly... odd.

Comment: So probably it's better to isolate the code that can do such crash, using new process? Or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want a function to run infinitely (as long as possible without interfering with the main program) put the code you have in a Daemon Process and it should run until you either crash something or until you kill the main process. I hope that helps.

Comment: I think it would work for my problem, but sadly your answer is somewhat irrelevant to the question, so I can't accept is as valid.